# Next step of evaluating the limit of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Find the limit of the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2n\vert x\vert}\frac{x+3}{x^4+3x^2+1} \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Obviously the part $\frac{e^{-2n\vert x\vert}x}{x^4+3x^2+1}$in integrand is eliminated since it's an odd function. It only needs to evaluate the value
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{3e^{-2n\vert x\vert}}{x^4+3x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}6n\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2nx}}{x^4+3x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
But I can't think out what to do next, simply applying L'Hospital's rule (as the answer in my last question shows) seems no use. How to evaluate it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the integral $I_n$ as given by

$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{6ne^{-2nx}}{x^4+3x^2+1}\,dx$$

Now, enforce the substitution $x\mapsto x/n$ to obtain

$$I_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{6e^{-2x}}{(x/n)^4+3(x/n)^2+1}\,dx$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Still have no idea, I cannot find the order of the integrand.

Comment: The integrand is dominated by $6e^{-2x}$, and $\int_{0}^\infty 6e^{-2x}\,dx$ converges.  Thus, it is legitimate to interchange the order of the limit and the integral.  Now, can you finish?

Comment: I understand, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Hi Mark ! Long Time no sée ! Cheers

Comment: Hi Claude!  How are you my friend?

Comment: (+1) As easy as that! Nice to see around again!

Comment: @Mittens Thank you.  I'm around ... it's just that there are not many posted questions that are interesting to me anymore.  All the cool kids are gone

Answer (score 3):

*Just for your curiosity since @Mark Viola provided the simplest and elegant solution.*

$$I_n=6n\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2nx}}{x^4+3x^2+1}\,{d}x
$$ Write $$x^4+3x^2+1=(x^2+a)(x^2+b)$$ where $a=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} $ and $b=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2} $  (fortunately positive).

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 1{(x^2+a)(x^2+b)}=\frac 1 {a-b} \left(\frac 1{x^2+b}-\frac 1{x^2+a}\right)$$ The required antiderivatives are known
$$\int \frac{e^{-k x}}{x^2+c}\,dx=\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{c}}\Big(e^{i k\sqrt{c} } \text{Ei}\left(-k \left(x+i \sqrt{c}\right)\right) -e^{-i k\sqrt{c} } \text{Ei}\left(-k \left(x-i \sqrt{c}\right)\right)\Big)$$ $\text{Ei}(.)$ being the exponential integral function. The definite integrals are also known.

Using series expansion
$$I_n= 3-\frac{9}{2
   n^2}+\frac{36}{n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ which is quite accurate even for small values of $n$ (for $n=10$ the absolute error is $5.37\times 10^{-4}$ and for $n=100$ it is $7.06\times 10^{-10}$).